# batch renaming files with datetime

Tags: string, bash, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I have lots of files like `[IMG|VID_]yyyymmdd_HHMMSS.jpg|png|mp4`, for instances,

```
20200123_122320.jpg|png|gif
20200123_122320.mp4
IMG_20200123_122320.jpg|png|gif
VID_20200123_122320.mp4
```

Regex `(\d{8})\D(\d{6})` of `rename` can extract the date and time str. But I don't know how to further rename them like `2020-01-23 12.23.20.jpg|mp4`.

Comment: `find -type f -print0 | rename -n -v -0 's/^.*(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)_(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d).*(\.(gif|jpg|mp4|png))$/$1-$2-$3 $4.$5.$6$7/'`

Comment: thx @jhnc. raises `unknown option 0`. after removing `-0`, it works.